# DBTNG Migrate: SQLite -> PostgreSQL fails because of custom fields

Tags: migrations, database

I am trying to migrate a website from a development setup that uses SQLite as a database backend to a production environment, where PostgreSQL is used as a DBMS.

My research so far has led me to the [DBTNG Migrator Module](http://drupal.org/project/dbtng_migrator), that promises to migrate a Drupal site to/from any database system the abstraction layer supports.

This is the database configuration in my `settings.php`:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'drupal',
      'username' => 'db_user',
      'password' => 'db_pass',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'pgsql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);

$databases['sqlite']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'sites/default/files/site.ht.sqlite',
  'driver' => 'sqlite',
  'prefix' => '',
);
```

Both databases are correctly being displayed in the DTNG Migration UI. However, when I run a Migration check for SQLite -> PostgreSQL, I get the following error message:

`field_data_field_custom does not existing in default`

`field_custom` is a custom field I defined in the development site.

Is there way to migrate my complete drupal setup, including custom fields and content types to PostgreSQL, using DBTNG Migrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question:

The migration should be run on an empty database. This way, everything gets replicated successfully.